# Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required and there's no corrupted files

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I encountered some errors and I don't know how to solve it can somebody help me?
my codes are based on some yt vid and I just did some minimal editing for it to work in colab
here's my code:

```
import os

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img_height = 28
img_width = 28
batch_size = 2
proj_path = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/G10-SIGHTHOUNDS"
proj_path = pathlib.Path(proj_path)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Input((28, 28, 3)),
        layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding="same"),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding="same"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(11),
    ]
)

#                      METHOD 1
# ==================================================== #
#             Using dataset_from_directory             #
# ==================================================== #

ds_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    proj_path,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",  # categorical, binary
    # class_names=['0', '1', '2', '3', ...]
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),  # reshape if not in this size
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
)

ds_validation = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    proj_path,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",  # categorical, binary
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),  # reshape if not in this size
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
)


def augment(x, y):
    image = tf.image.random_brightness(x, max_delta=0.05)
    return image, y


ds_train = ds_train.map(augment)

# Custom Loops
for epochs in range(10):
    for x, y in ds_train:
        # train here
        pass


model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

model.fit(ds_train, epochs=10, verbose=2)
```

and here's the error:

```
Drive already mounted at /content/gdrive; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/gdrive", force_remount=True).
Found 2749 files belonging to 11 classes.
Using 2200 files for training.
Found 2749 files belonging to 11 classes.
Using 549 files for validation.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-b39fbc2d162d> in <module>
     69 # Custom Loops
     70 for epochs in range(10):
---> 71     for x, y in ds_train:
     72         # train here
     73         pass

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7213 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   7214   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7215   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   7216 
   7217 

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

and I used an python codes to check if there's any corrupted files, there's actually none.

to answer my questions

Answer (score 0):

try to double check your files if and as I know you're using colab so it's probably because of uploading your file in drive something happened and corrupted some of your files

Comment: I just did what u suggest and you're right there's some corrupted file in images, thank youu

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter the type of error you have I first process the directory to ensure all the image files are proper images files with extensions that work with the ImageDataGenerator.. If I find a bad file I exclude it from the dataset. I create a dataframe of the form filepaths, labels where the filepaths columns contain the FULL path to the image file and labels contain the text label associated with the image file. Code to do that is shown below

```
def make_dataframes(train_path):
    import os
    import cv2
    import pandas as pd
    from tqdm import tqdm
    bad_images=[] 
    ht=0 # set initial value of height counter
    wt=0  # set initial value of width counter
    total_good_files=0 # set initial value of total number of good image files counter
    filepaths=[] # initialize list of filepaths
    labels=[] # initialize list of class labels
    classlist=sorted(os.listdir(train_path) )   # get a list of all the classes in alphanumeric order   
    for klass in classlist: # iterate through the list of classes
        good_file_count=0 # initialize the good_file count for this class
        classpath=os.path.join(train_path, klass) # define the full path to the class 
        flist=sorted(os.listdir(classpath)) # make a list of all the files for this class
        desc=f'{klass:15s}'
        for f in tqdm(flist, ncols=100, unit='files', desc=desc, colour='blue'):
            fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f) # create the full path to the image file
            index=f.rfind('.')
            ext=f[index+1:].lower() # the the file's extension
            if ext not in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'tiff', 'png', 'bmp'] :   # make sure the file extension is one that works with Keras                     
                bad_images.append(fpath) # if not a proper extension store the filepath in the bad images list
            else:                    
                try: # check if image files are defective if so do not include in dataframe
                    img=cv2.imread(fpath)
                    h=img.shape[0]
                    w=img.shape[1]
                    ht +=h # add images height and width to the counters
                    wt += w                    
                    good_file_count +=1   
                    total_good_files +=1
                    filepaths.append(fpath) # append the filepath to the list of valid filepaths
                    labels.append(klass) # append the file's class label to the labels list
                except:
                    bad_images.append(fpath) # if the image file is defective add the filepath to the list of bad images}        
    Fseries=pd.Series(filepaths, name='filepaths') # make a pandas series for the filenames and labels lists
    Lseries=pd.Series(labels, name='labels')
    df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1) # make a dataframe with columns filepaths and labels                   
    classes=sorted(df['labels'].unique())
    class_count=len(classes)    
    # calculate the average image height and with 
    have=int(ht/total_good_files)
    wave=int(wt/total_good_files)
    aspect_ratio=have/wave
    print('number of classes in processed dataset= ', class_count)    
    counts=list(df['labels'].value_counts())    
    print('the maximum files in any class in df is ', max(counts), '  the minimum files in any class in df is ', min(counts))
    print('df length: ', len(df) ) 
    if len(bad_images) == 0:
        print('All image files were properly processed and used in the dataframes')
    else:
        print(f'the are {len(bad_images)} bad image files and {total_good_files} proper image files in the dataset')
        for f in bad_images:
            print (f) 
    print (df.head())
    return train_df, classes, class_count, max(counts), min(counts), have, wave

train_path=r'/content/gdrive/MyDrive/G10-SIGHTHOUNDS'
make_dataframes(train_path)
```

Sorry a bit lengthy but I copied what I normally use and did not trim it down. The result is you get a dataframe with image files that have proper extensions and are valid image files. You can then use the dataframe with ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe to provide your generators If you need help on how to do that let me know.